# What do green/gray check mark icons mean in Facebook App Dashboard?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-center

In Facebook App Dashboard ( https://developers.facebook.com/apps/##########/ ) under Products I see 'Facebook Login' and 'Analytics' and green or gray check mark icons next to them. What do these icons mean?

[image: screenshot]

[Edit] The App is live. Login Permissions in App Review are approved by default (email, public_profile, user_friends). But one of my app has gray icon for Facebook Login and another app has green icon for Facebook Login. I can't find a pattern.

Comment: Well likely that you're completely done with configuring all the settings correctly and submitting for review what might require so in the one case, and in the other ... not?

Answer (score -1):

I also wondered about this until I noticed FB's App Center support page states:

"If your game is approved it may take up to 4 weeks and a minimum amount of players to be searchable in App Center."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/listing/

Comment: How's that related to OP's question?